# Media Player Class in Android the implementation scenario

Tags: android

for last three weeks I have worked on a Media Player in Android.I am trying to find a solution of how can I make my Media Player to change the song when it's already playing one.

Here is my `Listener` on the `RecyclerView`

```
    musicList.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getApplicationContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, final int position) {

                    currentPosition = position;

                    if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                        musicThread.start();
                    } else {
                        mediaPlayer.reset();

                    }

                }
            })
    );
}
```

and my `Thread` is this:

```
    final Thread musicThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                URL = getMusicURL(myDataset[currentPosition]);

                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(URL);
                    //mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // prepare async to not block main thread
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("TEST","Eroare: "+e.getMessage());
                }
            } catch (StorageApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("TEST","Eroare: "+e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a mess. First of all, you dont need a thread to play music, the own mediaplayer API does it for you when you call `mediaPlayer.start()`. However, you have to care about the time it takes to prepare the data source if you are for example streaming online music. For this, just use `mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()` and register a callback. When it has finished preparing, you can automatically start playing or do whatever you want.
If you want to change the data source, just follow the automaton map that you can find in MediaPlayer docs. Essentially, when the user selects another track, you register the call in your button listener, then reset the mediaPlayer, and recall all prepare, start... cycle again. By the way, it is advised to deploy all your mediaplayer code into a service so that it can keep playing even though the user has closed your activity.

Comment: To register the callback do I need anything else or only prepareAsync ?

Comment: Just call this method in your mediaPlayer `setOnPreparedListener (MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener listener)` . I highly recommend you to read the official documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html